# Access Denied when using Explorer in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I try to go to C:/Users/All Users//AppData/Local/Application Data I get the dialog 
"C:/Users.../Application Data is not accessable. Access is denied."
I am the only user and have Administrator privileges. How do I gain access?

Comment: make a rightclick on the folder, go to the security settings, make you to the owner of this folder and give your account full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

That folder is not a real folder, but rather a junction to the C:\ProgramData folder, which is why you are unable to access it from Explorer using the normal method.